# Using Mountain Lion Dictation

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

How do I use the OS X Mountain Lion dictation features in my app? Or can I only use `NSSpeechRecognizer`?

Comment: Those who are voting to close this as “not a real question”: Why do you think it's not a real question?

Comment: Nobody's talked about it, and I can't seem to find any docs related to the dictation feature.  I think you're stuck with NSSpeechRecognizer for now.

Comment: I've decided that the best thing to do for now is to use a text field in the app, let the person use Dictation as normal in the text field, and then retrieve the text field's value.